# Show that a function defined by $Tu=u, \forall u\in U$ and $Tv=0, \forall v \notin U$ is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $U \not= V$ be a subspace. Show that the function $T: V \to V$ defined by $Tu = u$ for all $u \in U$ and $Tv = 0$ for all $v \not\in U$ is not linear.

I do not understand how can this be the case? If we think about T being linear if $\forall v, u$ we have,
$$
f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v) \space \text{and} \space f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)
$$
then $Tv = 0$ for all $v \not\in U$.In other words, $T$ is constant for all $v \not\in U$. Even looking at the definition, $Tv = 0$ for all $v \not\in U$ satisfies both conditions from definition. So how can this function not be linear? Could it have something to do with linear independence of $v$ and $u$?

Comment: **Hint:** Find elements $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$ such that $x+y\notin U$. Does that help?

Comment: In fact, $x+y \notin U$ is automatic. Just take $x \in U, y \notin U$ and show that $T(x+y) \neq Tx+Ty$.

Comment: Indeed it is, but in that type of exercise that is also to be proven, thus me formating the hint this way.

Comment: Note that $U\neq V$ is crucial here (else you get the zero map, which is obviously linear). So you need to use that, and do something with elements not in $U$ as @AnthonySaint-Criq suggests.

Comment: @Mark Did you mean $U \neq \{0\}$?  (otherwise, did you mean the identity map?)

Comment: I understand that I essentially need to find $x, y: (x+y)\in V$. Essentially that adding $y$ to $x$ takes it outside the subspace $U$. That is possible because $U\neq V$, but I'm not sure that I can say anything else there?

Comment: Try to gain some intuition in a familiar case first. Consider $\mathbb R^2$ and $U$ some 1d subspace, say the x-axis. Now $T$ is the identity on the x-axis, but sends everything outside of that axis to $0$. Why can't this be a linear map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that we can find $u \in U\setminus\{0\}$ and $v \in V\setminus U$ such that $u+v \notin U$. For these vectors $u,v$ we would have that:

1. $T(u+v) = 0$, because $u+v \notin U$
2. $Tu + Tv = u + 0 = u \ne 0$

This means that $T(u+v) \ne Tu + Tv$ for the particular vectors and therefore  $T$ is not linear. But can we find such vectors? Yes.

Since $U \ne V$, we can choose some $v \in V\setminus U$. We know for sure that $u+v \notin U$ because, if this was not the case, i.e. if $u+v \in U$, then $(u+v)+(-u) = v$ would also be in $U$ and this would be a contradiction.